# ClassNotFound Exception: org.postgresql.Driver Using Geotool: gt-imagemosiac-jdbc-x.x.jar

Tags: postgis, java, geotools, image-mosaic, image-pyramids

I am a newbie to GIS, coming from a strict MIS background. Anyway, I have been having a little challenge for the past couple of days trying to import tiles and pyramids into my database. Using a tutorial I found [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html). Whenever I run this command on windows (8.1);

`java -jar <your_geoserver_install_dir>/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-{version}.jar import  -config <your geoserver data dir>/coverages/osm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix tileosm -tileTNPrefix tileosm -dir tiles -ext png`

I get this exception

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Drive
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.start(Import.java:366)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Toolbox.main(Toolbox.java:46)`

I have already copied the postgressql driver jar file to my java runtime, lib/ext directory. which is found here; `C:\java\jre7\lib\ext`. I have also tried to write a java program to test for the driver and it works fine, and by the way I also have Netbeans(8.0.2) installed and the driver is working fine in there too. But I don't know why I still get that exception.

Comment: which JDK do you have installed?

Comment: jdk1.7.0 update 72

Comment: openjdk or oracle or ibm ?

Comment: I am using oracle

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930782/call-java-jar-myfile-jar-with-additional-classpath-option

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:<location of jdbc.jar> -jar <your_geoserver_install_dir>/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-{version}.jar import  -config <your geoserver data dir>/coverages/osm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix tileosm -tileTNPrefix tileosm -dir tiles -ext png
```

I solved this problem via this method. And you can see the tutorial [here.](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/jdbc/import.html)

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu (at least 18.04) the following can work:

`sudo apt install libpostgresql-jdbc-java
cd /usr/share/java
sudo ln -s postgresql.jar postgresql-jdbc.jar`